# Javascript does not recognise two url parameters as equal even though they are equal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, url, input

I am using React.js and trying to filter store products based on the parameters that the user has chosen from a set of . When clicking on an input, "onChange" fires a function that takes the  name and the  value, encodes it, and puts it into the URL search query as a key/value pair.

Everything is working fine, except in one instance. When the user changes their mind and picks a different answer in the , my javascript code is supposed to:

1. Get the current URL parameters,
2. Check if the  name is already in the URL param as a key,
3. If it already is inside the URL param, don't add a new param, instead change the value of the key,
4. Take the new set of URL parameters and use those instead.

The good news is that this works for most key/pairs. For example:

1. { Color: #fffff } would look like this in the URL "?Color=%23FFFFFF". If the user changed the color the  URL parameter also changed.

But...

2. I have a  name "WITH USB 3 PORTS" that looks like this, when added to the URL param - "?With%2520USB%25203%2520ports=Yes" , but when I try to change the value to "No" in the  for some reason my javascript thinks that "With%2520USB%25203%2520ports" is not the same as "With%2520USB%25203%2520ports". It does not do this for "Color" or any other key/value pair.

Can anyone explain why this might be the case and how to stop this from happening?

To give some more context, I use:

1. window.location.search -> to get the URL params
2. encodeURIComponent()   -> to prepare the values to be used a key/value pairs
3. new URLSearchParams()  -> to create the new params
4. window.location.href   -> to refer the user to the new URL (I will later use history.pushState())

### UPDATE #1

Based on @Cerbrus recommendation, I added the code that creates this issue.

```
    //* Change the url params when the user changes the filter inputs
    changeUrlParam = () => {

        //* Prepare localhost variable
            const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000'

        //* Get current path name
            const pathName = window.location.pathname;
        
        //* Get current url parameters if any
            const urlQuery = window.location.search;
            const pureParam = urlQuery.replace('?', '');

        //* Create a new param
            const params = urlQuery.length < 1 ? new URLSearchParams() : new URLSearchParams(pureParam);
    
        //* Prepare the value/key pair
            const key = encodeURIComponent('With Usb 3 Ports');
            const value = 'Yes';

        //* If the params - ARE NOT SET
            if(urlQuery.length < 1) {
                //* Apend new value to it
                    params.append(key, value);

        //* If the params - ARE SET
            } else {
                //* Check if the param in question is already set
                    const paramTest = urlQuery.includes(key);

                //* If present - change it
                    if(paramTest === true) { 
                        //* Change the old value to the new value
                            params.set(key, value);
                //* If not present - apend it
                    } else {
                        //* Add the new value to the exsisting param
                            params.append(key, value);
                    }
            }

        //* Prepare the new url
            const newUrl = baseUrl + pathName + '?' + params.toString();
    
        //* Go to the new url
            return window.location.href = newUrl;
    };
```

Comment: Please add a (runnable) code snippet that reproduces your problem. There are so many ways there could be a mistake in your code, we can't really help you from just a problem description, and a list of used methods. See also [mcve].

Comment: %2520 looks funky. Also you state you have `WITH USB 3 PORTS` ... but clealry you don't. Since you then show encoded `With USB 3 ports` perhaps there's a case problem? Or it may be that leading `?` you show once

Comment: @Jaromanda - "WITH USB 3 PORTS" is how it shows up on the <label> because I use CSS to make the label appear with uppercase letters, but in the code - the label appears as "With USB 3 ports" and thus is encoded like that and is compared to that version not the "WITH USB 3 PORTS".

Comment: You probably don't need to `encodeURIComponent` by hand.

Comment: @AKX . I probably don't, but it is easier to encode (since the key/value pairs need to be URL-safe) and decode the key later with decodeURIComponent() when I need to use the parameter in HTML. Originally, I got rid of all the whitespaces in the key and used that as a param - simple. Yet, the same issue would still be present.

Comment: @ghost Well, let me rephrase: you definitely don't. `URLSearchParams` does that for you.

Comment: @AKX I understand the issue now. Thank you for explaining the fact that, if I have both URLSearchParams and encodeURIComponent, I am encoding the string twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things.

- `URLSearchParams` deals with decoding and encoding strings by itself, so doing `encodeURIComponent` confuses it (indeed, a double-encoded URI component isn't the same as the non-encoded one)
- The whole exists/set/append thing seems to be a no-op; just `set` the single value you need.

Here's a standalone function; replace the `search` argument in the invocation(s) with `window.location.search` when you'd use it in your component.

```
function mangleParams(search, key, value) {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(search.replace(/^\?/, ''));
  params.set(key, value);
  return params.toString();
}

console.log(mangleParams('', 'With USB 3 ports', 'No'));
console.log(mangleParams('?With%20USB%203%20ports=Yes', 'With USB 3 ports', 'Heck yeah'));
console.log(mangleParams('?With%20USB%203%20ports=Yes&Other feature=Sure', 'With USB 3 ports', 'Nice'));
```

This outputs

```
With+USB+3+ports=No
With+USB+3+ports=Heck+yeah
With+USB+3+ports=Nice&Other+feature=Sure
```

(so the %20s are also normalized to +es, and all encoding works as it should).

Comment: Wow, this just works - it's shorter, easy to understand and read + fixes the issue. Thank you!